# How do I set y value as 0 for missing x values in dataframe for line graph (matplotlib, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, missing-data, linegraph

I have a dataframe used to plot line graph. Dataframe looks like this:
[image]

This is how my line graph currently looks:
[image: Line graph]

Code to plot line graph:

```
ax  = df_dec18.set_index('Day').plot(figsize=(10,5), grid=True)
ax.set_xlabel('Day')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of reviews')
ax.set_title('Number of reviews published each month in year 2018 (September onwards) for HP 15q ds0058TU')
t = [df_dec18['Reviews_published'].min(), df_dec18['Reviews_published'].max()]
plt.xticks(range(0,31))
```

How do I set the x values for say, day 7,8,9 to 0 as there was no review published on that day. I want to do this so my line graph y value shows 0 for the given day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I know, you can't directly tell matplotlib to put zero inside missing data. Matplotlib just ignore the missing data, and connect the line between points you have a data on them. If you want missing data to be zero, you should do it as part of your processing of dataframe.

Such processing can be:

```py
df_dec18 = df_dec18.set_index('Day')
df_new_dec18 = pd.DataFrame({"Day":range(1,32), "Reviews_published": 0}).set_index("Day")
df_new_dec18["Reviews_published"]=df_dec18["Reviews_published"]
df_new_dec18.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

At first, I put "Day" column as index for the dataframe. You are working with time series (I guess), I think using your day as index is more convenient. Then I created a new df, this time with whole days in December, not only the ones you have data on them. Again, as your are working with time series I believe it's a more correct and "clean" way to handle your dataframe. This dataframe also use "Day" as index.

Then I just used `fillna` to give zeroes to days you have no information on. Then your line graph will be just fine. Notice you will need `ax  = df_dec18.plot(figsize=(10,5), grid=True)` without `set_index` as "Day" column is already the index.

P.S: for next time, please put example of your dataframe inline (just like your code) and not as an image. For your linegraph, just copy it - right click on juypter and "copy image" and paste it here. Don't share your entire screen.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Also yes, I will put my dataframe inline next time, sorry for the inconvenience.